# Spring Security StrictHttpFirewall.setAllowedHostnames: Why `localhost` in whitelist, but still denied?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Java 11, Spring Boot 2.3.12.RELEASE, Windows 11 x64. With CMD

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1848]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>hostname
DESKTOP-84LARLB

C:\Users\admin>
```

Configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    //...
    StrictHttpFirewall strictHttpFirewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    strictHttpFirewall.setAllowBackSlash(true);
    strictHttpFirewall.setAllowedHostnames(hostName ->             
    hostName.equals("http://localhost"));
    strictHttpFirewall.setAllowedHostnames(hostName -> hostName.equals("DESKTOP-84LARLB"));

strictHttpFirewall.setAllowedHostnames(hostName ->             
    hostName.equals("localhost"));
```

I call by Postman:

```
GET http://localhost:8083/foo/bar/baa
```

error

```java
2023-07-05 14:20:33.115 ERROR--[25-nio-8083-exec-2] [                                        ]o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost]        :Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the domain localhost is untrusted.
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedUntrustedHosts(StrictHttpFirewall.java:382)
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:337)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Why `localhost` in whitelist, but still denied?

Comment: It is the same error, so strange.

Comment: Determines which hostnames should be allowed. The default is to allow any hostname.

Comment: Do you mean, in the code, I putted `localhost` to blacklist?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#servlet-httpfirewall) the HttpFirewall needs to be a separate Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Security {
...
  @Bean
  public StrictHttpFirewall httpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall strictHttpFireWall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    strictHttpFirewall.setAllowBackSlash(true);
    strictHttpFirewall.setAllowedHostnames(hostName ->             
    hostName.equals("http://localhost"));

    strictHttpFirewall.setAllowedHostnames(hostName ->             
    hostName.equals("localhost"));
  }
...
}
```

I tested this locally and this works. The default is to allow every hostname, so putting it in a bean should work even without explicitly adding localhost

Answer (score 0):

[image]

default allow all host, if point out specific host, it is denied.

Comment: *if point out specific host, it is denied* - that is not a very good name for the method  and seems to opposite of what it used to do in previous versions

Comment: Thank you for confirmation about this. The name of method made me lost 2 days.

Comment: I don't think this is actually the case, just that the documentation you are quoting is misleading
See here: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/StrictHttpFirewall.html#setAllowedHostnames(java.util.function.Predicate) and here:
https://github.com/jzheaux/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/StrictHttpFirewall.java#L470

Comment: I tried on my Localhost with Spring Boot 2.3.12.RELEASE, with `localhost`, It denied `localhost`.